# Change the Text inside a specific <td> with a class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have table and the data inside the table are dynamically filled with php. 
When I press the button, a ajax request will be started. After I did what I wanted to do with ajax, I'm getting the new name of a product back. I want to replace this new data that comes with ajax, with the `<td>` that got the "replace" class and which is the closest `<td>` from the button I have pressed.

But I wasn't able to do it.

```
       @foreach($products as $key => $product)
               <tr>
                     <td>aaa</td>
                     <td>bbb</td>
                     <td class="status">{{ $product->name }}</td>
                     <td>
                            <button type="button" class="save btn btn-danger" product-id="{{$product->id}}">
                                   <span>Save</span>
                             </button>
                     </td>
               </tr>
       @endforeach
```

I've tried many things like this:

```
    $(".save").on('click', function () {
         all my ajax here... ,

         success: function (data) {
             $(this).closest(".status").html(data); // I tried this
             $(this).closest("td.status").html(data); // or this
             $(this).closest("tr").find(".status").html(data); // or this
             $(this).closest("tr").find(".status").html(data); // or this
        },
    });
```

and some other things, but nothing worked at all. 
Data only contains a simple string.

Comment: Your last two lines have syntax errors you'd see in the console.

Comment: You have no element with the class of `status` `status` != `replace`

Comment: yes you're right, that was more a mistake I did while I was writing the question, in my code it was right. But haven't worked in this way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` in your ajax callbacks is the jqXhr object unless you change it with context
Then you can use `closest` and `find` to select the field

```
$(".save").on('click', function () {
     all my ajax here... ,
     context: this,
     success: function (data) {
         $(this).closest("tr").find(".replace").html(data); // or this
    }
});
```